# Convert .sdf database to .mdf database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, sql-server-ce

I have this SQL Server CE database (with more tables and data) which I would like to convert to SQL 2008 because I want use it in Server (application need to used by many). I am using SQL 2008 express and C#.

Please suggest how I can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a good idea is to try microsoft (free) tool, Sql Server Management Studio :
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7593

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried the Data Migration Wizard?

Anyhow, you might find this interesting: 
http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com/

Original source:

http://bembengarifin-tech.blogspot.com/2008/08/generate-script-export-data-from-sql-ce.html

Comment: The "SQL Compact data and schema script utility" did the thing.

Answer (score 2):

This [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36345/Using-LINQ-to-SQL-with-SQL-Server-Compact?msg=3049179#xx3049179xx) should help you. It shows you how to convert `.sdf` to `.cs` object using `SQLMetal.exe`

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft WebMatrix uses Compact SQL (.sdf file) by default. In the Database view, if SQL SVR is installed, there is a Migrate to SQL Server top menu item.  There is also a menu selection to install SQL Server.  Both WebMatrix and (a version of) SQL SVR 2008 are free to install.

Answer (score 0):

You could use MSDeploy to migrate your database:

http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/03/migrate-sql-server-compact-database-to.html